# Cross validation in SPSS

Tags: cross-validation

I need to conduct cross validation of my data to check for predictive validity. This is what I did so far. I divided the sample into two sub-samples(50-50). In SPSS, I then used the split variable to instruct SPSS to keep the data divided into two-sub samples while running  regression.  Post this I got two regression outputs. And now I'm stuck here. The supervisor wants me to test for predictive validity and using each sub-sample I need to test models and compute r for predictions versus actual values in the hold out sample. How do I do it in SPSS?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: If `Y` is your dependent variable, compute a new variable `Y2` which equals `Y` in your model sample and `sysmis` in your hold out sample. Run the regression on `Y2` (without split files), and then save the predicted values. These will be the predicted values from the model sample, extended to the hold out sample.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please correct me if I go wrong. 1) I need to calculate Y2 and sysmis for both sub-samples? 2) sysmis in point (1) is just a label and it can also be called Y3, right? 2) Do I choose standardized or unstandardized predicted values in SPSS? 3). "Run the regression on Y2 (without split files), and then save the predicted values" This means I have to make Y2 as the dependent variable and I can name the predicted values as Y4. 4) Finally, once I have the predicted values I would need to find correlation between Y4 and sysmis (or Y3)? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Save unstandardized - otherwise sounds about right. Not sure I'd use correlation, absolute or root mean square error would be IMO more informative, but you can do these in addition to correlation (to make everyone happy!)

Comment: @AndyW, it looks like you have effectively answered the question. Consider posting your comments as an answer.

Comment: There you go @RichardHardy - although it might be reasonable to close the question as just related to nuts-and-bolts of stat programming as well (at least how I answered the question anyway).

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways you might go about doing this in SPSS. The system missing trick, or creating separate datasets and scoring the model. Below are illustrations of both using simulated data.

```
*Creating simulated data.
SET SEED 10.
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP Id = 1 TO 100.
END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM. 
DATASET NAME Sim.

COMPUTE X = RV.NORMAL(0,1).
COMPUTE Y = 2 + 0.5*X + RV.NORMAL(0,1).
COMPUTE Test = (Id > 50).
FORMATS Test (F1.0).
EXECUTE.

************************************************.
*Method 1, using the system missing trick.
IF (Test = 0) Y2 = Y.
REGRESSION
 /DEPENDENT Y2
 /METHOD=ENTER X
 /SAVE=PRED(Pred1).
*Can see Pred1 is applied to the whole dataset.
************************************************.

************************************************.
*Method 2, saving to a file and scoring the output.

*Change to a location your personal machine can write to.
CD 'C:\Users\axw161530\Desktop\Articles_To_Read'.

*Creating seperate test and scoring datasets.
DATASET COPY Test.
DATASET ACTIVATE Test.
SELECT IF Test = 1.
EXECUTE.
*Could also do TEMPORARY & SELECT IF to accomplish similar.
*Without making seperate datasets.

DATASET ACTIVATE Sim.
SELECT IF Test = 0.
REGRESSION
 /DEPENDENT Y
 /METHOD=ENTER X
 /OUTFILE=MODEL('LinTest.xml').

DATASET ACTIVATE Test.
MODEL HANDLE NAME=LinReg FILE='LinTest.xml'.
COMPUTE Pred2 = ApplyModel(LinReg,'PREDICT').
EXECUTE.
MODEL CLOSE NAME=LinReg.
*Can see that this is the same as the prior two.

*Cleaning up model file.
ERASE FILE = 'LinTest.xml'.
************************************************.
```

The second makes it clearer there are seperate datasets, and you can run whatever stats you want on the `Test` dataset between predicted and observed.